# null value in column "city_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This error happens when I tried to use Django admin to add a new entry in the database. This error shows even I tried to add a new state. What's wrong with my model?

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

class State(models.Model):
    state_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'state'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state
```

Comment: Your model looks fine, did you run makemigrations and migrate? can you show us your migration file?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem:
It's a problem with my PostgreSQL database. This error shows even when I run `INSERT` in the database. So the problem is because my `PRIMARY KEY` is not a `SERIAL` value, rather, it's an `INTEGER`, thus it cannot auto increment when I insert a new value.

To solve this problem:

1. Delete the old integer id as well as all the foreign key constraint on it.
2. `ALTER TABLE city ADD COLUMN city_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`
3. Reconnect tables with new foreign keys

After that, my problem is solved. Hope this helps other people facing a similar problem!